# Unable to connect to a server via proxy

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to connect to a server by providing a URL. However, I am getting the following error

```
11:48:41.936 [qtp62610667-23] INFO  pl.imguploadimg -   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at pl.imguploadimg.webapp.service.HTMLService.findImagesInInputStream(HTMLService.java:36)
    at pl.imguploadimg.webapp.controller.BaseController.socketConnection(BaseController.java:49)
```

This problem occurred when switched to LAN. Below is my code:

```
@Value("${useSystemProxy}")
Boolean useSystemProxy;

public void findImagesInInputStream(String url) throws IOException {

    if (useSystemProxy) {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    }

    URL postURL = new URL(url);
    InputStream inputStream = postURL.openStream();

    findMIME(inputStream);
}
```

Here `String url = "https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en";`

Also, the same program runs when it is in a main function

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");

    URL myURL = new URL("http://www.macdowellcolony.org/WorkSampleRequirements.pdf");
    URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
    InputStream isr = myURL.openStream();
    myURLConnection.connect();
    System.out.println(myURLConnection.getHeaderFields());
    System.out.println(myURLConnection.getContentType());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code changes worked out :

```
@Value("${useSystemProxy}")
Boolean useSystemProxy;

@Value("${proxyURL}")
String proxyURL;

@Value("${proxyPort}")
String proxyPort;

@Value("${username}")
String username;

@Value("${password}")
String password;

public void findImagesInInputStream(String url) throws IOException {

    if (useSystemProxy) {
        System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", proxyURL);
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", username);
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", password);
    }

    URL postURL = new URL(url);
    InputStream inputStream = postURL.openStream();

    findMIME(inputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is on the server-side. When server detects that the client ip is not allowed then it just refuses connection (just as stacktrace says).